# Peak current mode control question

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, control

I read two different figures about the peak current mode control block diagram, and I am confused about one thing, please see the below two figures.

In this figure, voltage loop output is connected to the comparator (+), the other figure, voltage loop output is connected to the comparator (-). I would like to know which one is correct, and why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The top one is supposed to be current mode sync buck (i.e. having two switches) but the block diagram is wrong.

Comment: For the first one, the switch shorts Vin to GND. Obviously wrong. The second one shows an NMOS device, which needs a gate voltage higher than Vin. Or, a PMOS would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2nd is correct.

In peak current mode, when the inductor current reaches the level set by the controller, the latch is reset and the highs-side switch turns off.

With the logic shown, high current will drive the comparator high which resets the latch and consequently the PWM.

Comment: +1 and it's worth to put a [correct block diagram](http://www.powerelectronictips.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Figure-1.jpg) of current mode sync buck.